# Symfony 5.0.8 - How to check if entity has relation record from with in twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have User, Post and Bookmark entities.

inside the Bookmark entity:

- user -> ManyToOne
- Post -> ManyToOne
- date -> datetime

I'm displaying a post page like so "post/{id}"
inside of the post display page, how can I check if the user has bookmarked this post?

Tried:

```
{% if post.bookmarks.contains(app.user) %} 

{% if app.user.bookmarks.contains(post) %} // I thought it might do it magically

{% if app.user.bookmarks.contains({'post': post}) %}
```

I think it's looking for the bookmark object and I can't provide it without doing a for loop.

**Update:**

With the help of some people in the php chat came up with this solution:

```
{% if app.user.bookmarks|filter(b => b.property.id == property.id)|length %}
```

However, I'm wondering if there is a more effective solution that can be done in the controller and then passed to the view.

**Update**

I don't like doing logic in the view, so the solution I found was in side he `Post` entity I created a function:

```
public function isPostBookmarkedByUser(User $user, Post $post): bool
{
    $bookmarks = $user->getBookmarks();

    foreach ($bookmarks as $bookmark) {
        if ($bookmark->getPost() === $post) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then I used this function inside the view like so:

```
{% if post.isBookmarkedByUser(app.user, post) %}
   <p>You bookmarked this post</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is there any good reason for doing that in Twg? Logic should be contained in the models or controllers, not in the views

Comment: Yes, I agree. but, I don't know how :)

Comment: So, what have you tried? Extending your model should be pretty simple

Comment: Well you can see what I have tried in the question :) I haven't tried in the Entity, because I don't know how.

Comment: I can image something like `public function isBookmarkedByUser(User $user) : bool {return $this->getBookmarks()->contains($user);}`

Comment: Yeah, why not go for that? If that is a function on your model, you can safely call it in Twig

Comment: Will this `$this->getBookmarks()->contains($user) ? true : false;` find the user or the  bookmark? or is doing some magic in the background?

Comment: Just try to use it. Debugging it is possible through XDebug, vardump, echo,...

Comment: returns false regardless.

Comment: @KerrialBeckettNewham please post your solution as an answer instead of an edit of your question, which should stay only a "question"

Comment: @Veve will do. Just waiting for some other answers first. maybe there is a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's a lot of ways to obtain this, and there's not better or worst.
Depending on what makes sense in your domain, for example, you can provide a public method onto `Post` entity; something like `isBookmarkedByUser($user)` or you can add it to `User` entity; like `hasBookmarkedPost($post)`.
You can also make a [Twig function](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) and query directly the DB (avoiding looping and lazy-loading all the records of the Collection) or, maybe, you can loop directly in twig.
As you can see from my answer, the possibilities are endless. Pick your posion: it's up to you.